# SSML Confusion - Alexa Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service, ssml

I am a complete novice to building Alexa skills.

I have managed to build and send a skill live, but now want to improve it.

I primarily want to change the way Alexa speaks my code... I don't understand how to implement SSML into my Node.js code...

This is part of my code...

```
"AMAZON.CancelIntent": function () {
    this.response.speak("Thank you for using The Bible Geek. If you enjoyed your learning experience, why not leave us a 5 star review and let us know if there are topics that you would like The Bible Geek to cover. Goodbye")
    this.emit(':responseReady');   },
```

I'd really like to be able to implement a pause such as `<break time="3s"/>`

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Using **SSML Tags** is really simple in your case you just need to add this break time tag **`<break time="3s"/>`** in the response where you need a pause of 3 seconds.

For example in your code snippet above you just need to do this:

(Note: use template string operator (``) rather than single ('') or double quotes (""))

```js
 this.response.speak(`There is a three second pause here <break time="3s"/> then the speech continues.`)
 this.emit(':responseReady');
```

Comment: I tried that, but it won't let me use tags within the code for some reason!?

It calls a parsing error???

Comment: use template string operator (``) rather than single ('') or double quotes ("") and try again.

Comment: or can you please provide details of the error.. edit your question and add error details..